# I need to skip empty cells in my vba button and open when is not empty

Tags: excel, vba

I have a button which opens a query of links whenever I click on it, however sometimes a field in my query is empty and I need my code to keep going and skip the empty cell, how can I solve that

I've already tried IsEmpty and couldn't reach the expected resultl. VBA world is quite new for me, so if you spot any silly mistake or not optimized method warn me. The code down here is from before I tried to skip the empty cells

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim SelecRng As Range

    Set SelecRng = ("F3:F44")

    Each Cell In SelecRng
    Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
    objShell.Run (Cell)
    Next
End Sub
```

I don't wanna see the error whenever I try to open some links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim SelecRng As Range

Set SelecRng = ("F3:F44") 'I would add a reference to the WB and WS here. Now it always refers to the active WB & WS

For Each Cell In SelecRng
If not Cell.Value = "" Then
    Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
    objShell.Run (Cell.Value)
End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, it fits like a glove for me

Answer (score 1):

Tim Stack provides a good answer, however I would recommend running the check with `= vbNullString` instead of `= ""`, and to use `Cell.value2` instead of `Cell.value`.

In this precise example that would not really matter, but in some other cases it could; so better take the habit now.

That would be:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim SelecRng As Range

    Set SelecRng = ("F3:F44") 'I would add a reference to the WB and WS here. Now it always refers to the active WB & WS

    For Each Cell In SelecRng
        If Cell.Value2 <> vbNullString Then
            Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
            objShell.Run (Cell.Value2)
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```